# Every $a^p$ is in the center of the multiplicative group for every element $a$ of $G$ where $|G| = p^3$ and $p$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is the problem:

Every $a^p$ is in the center of the multiplicative group for every element $a$ of $G$ where $|G| = p^3$ and $p$ is prime.

I read the solution online however I am a bit confused in few portions.

If $G$ is abelian there is nothing to prove. Otherwise $|Z(G)| = p$ and $G/Z(G) \cong \mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$. Hence for any $a \in G$ we have $\overline{a}^p = 1$ where $\overline{a}$ denotes the image of $a$ in $G/Z(G)$. Therefore $a^p \in Z(G)$

I don't get this part:

Hence for any $a \in G$ we have $\overline{a}^p = 1$ where $\overline{a}$ denotes the image of $a$ in $G/Z(G)$, how do we conclude that $\overline{a}^p = 1$?

Can anyone please clear this confusion?

Comment: You've said what $G/Z(G)$ is, and that group only has elements of order $p$ or $1$. So $\bar{a}^p=\bar{1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ and $H$ are two groups and $(g,h) \in G \times H$, then $o\big((g,h)\big) = \text{lcm}(o(g),o(h))$. So, if we take $G = H = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, all non-identity elements of $G$ and $H$ have order $p$. So what could be the least common multiple of orders of those elements? Could it be $p^2$ for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Without direct products. For nonabelian $G$, $|G/Z(G)|=p^2$, so for a noncentral element $a\in G$, $Z(G)a$ has order either $p$ or $p^2$. In the latter case, $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, and hence $G$ is abelian: contradiction. So $Z(G)a$ has order $p$ for every noncentral $a\in G$, and hence $a^p\in Z(G)$, which then holds for every $a\in G$ (central and noncentral).